# How to cast varchar in varbinary?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I try to update column value by appending varchar strings.

```
MyTable{
   Id int,
   MyValueColumn varbinary(max),
   MyParamColumn varchar(50)
}
```

how i append:

```
'{"ZoneId":'+cast ([MyValueColumn] as varchar)+', "ZoneName":"'+[MyParamColumn]+'"}'
```

And this return correct value:

```
    '{"ZoneId":1018, "ZoneName":"szz"}'
```

But now i cast result in varbinary and cast it again in varchar (for check varbinary correcy):

```
    cast (cast('{"ZoneId":'+cast ([MyValueColumn] as varchar)+', "ZoneName":"'+[MyParamColumn]+'"}' as varbinary) as varchar)
```

and result:

```
'{"ZoneId":1018
```

Whats can be wrong?

Comment: Bad copy/paste? Check your last sql statement for accuracy.

Comment: @lc. Im sure than copy query correctly in question. Can't find an error.

Comment: @Io. Oh thrully i lost one quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using `cast` to `varbinary` without explicit specification of length default length is 30.

So some trimming of your data can occurs if you're using `varbinary`, not `varbinary(n)` or `varbinary(max)` explicitly.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx) for reference.

**NOTE:**

Also you have missed `'` in your query: `cast (cast({"ZoneId":'` should be `cast (cast('{"ZoneId":'`

**Update**

I've created simple example:

```
declare @text varchar(50)
select @text = '{"ZoneId":'+cast (1018 as varchar)+', "ZoneName":"'+'szz'+'"}'

select cast(cast(@text as varbinary) as varchar)
select cast(cast(@text as varbinary(max)) as varchar(max))
```

it gives you trimmed text in first cast and original untrimmed text when we're using `varbinary(max)`

Comment: Using varbinary(max) and varchar(max) helps me. Thank you!